# Python shutil move merges files

Tags: python, file, rename, move, shutil

Hey I am trying to use the shutil move function rename a bunch of files in a directory incrementally.  Example, take files a.txt, b.txt, c.txt and rename them all into 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, and so forth.  Right now when I call the shutil.move function it will take all the files and make just one "1" file.  Oddly enough when I print out the new path I make, it will increment the path just fine.

Here is my code:

```
absWorkingDir = os.path.abspath('.')

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    newFile = os.path.join(absWorkingDir, file)
    newPath = os.path.join(absWorkingDir, showName + " - s" + seasNum + \
                           "e%02d" % (os.listdir('.').index(file) + 1,))

    print(newPath)
    shutil.move(newFile, newPath)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are constantly changing and relisting the directory when setting up newPath.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate @akg ?  Wouldn't I want a new path for each file?  I don't think I understand completely.

Comment: In the `newPath = ... ` you read the directory again with `os.listdir('.')` however in the second iteration this will read the modified directory.

Comment: Oh I understand now, how do I work around this?  I was using the listdir to get the index so I could increment the numbers but now I'm back to square one I suppose.

Comment: You can simply create a counter and increment it in the loop.

Comment: How could I do this to where it will increment in the path and for each file?  Sorry for all the questions I'm relatively new to coding, you've been a huge help so far!

Comment: OK. So it seems like you are sorting series (or subtitles). So the incremental naming would not be enough, the order matters. How do the filenames look like? Oh, and also you should leave out your python script from the order (you are using '.' as directory that's why I assume it is in the same directory).

Comment: The files are just any sort of video file.  And I used '.' just because that's how I learned to loop through a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the clarification this should help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

skip = ['py', 'pyc']
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.split('.')[-1] not in skip]
files.sort()

showName = "ASD"
seasNum = 1

episode = 1
for f in files:
    ext = f.split('.')[-1]
    shutil.move(f, "%s-S%02de%02d.%s"%(showName, seasNum, episode, ext))
    episode+=1
```

Pay attention to the condition in the list comprehension.

Usage:

```
➜  ls
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt  d.avi  move.py
➜  python move.py 
➜  ls
ASD-S01e01.txt  ASD-S01e02.txt  ASD-S01e03.txt  ASD-S01e04.avi  move.py
```

Comment: So will this always start at 0 for the episode number?  And I'm guessing I'll have to hard code or take user input for different file extensions?

Comment: You can use `f.split('.')[-1] in ['mp4', 'avi', 'mpeg']` in the `if` part or `f.split('.')[-1] not in ['txt', 'srt', 'py']`. I edited the answer for you. I also changed the first num to 1 :P

Comment: This is becoming way more complicated than I initially thought.  I'm gonna have to take a look at this when I get home from work in a few hours.  Thanks for all your amazing help I'll post back if I have any additional questions.